# What append during shutdown process in embedded Linux?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, init

What append in Linux when the user type "halt" in? Is there any script that force process to end as soon as possible? If yes, is there any way to schedule process shutdown?

The purpose of this scheduler will be force GPIO management to be the last one to exit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending init system it can force killing services. General way to shedule stop order is sorting "K*" links in `/etc/rc.d/`

To understand deeper first look in `/etc/inittab` at lines:

```
::shutdown:/etc/rc.d/rcS K shutdown
::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r
```

In this example shutdown sheduled by `/etc/rc.d/rcS` script.

After typing `halt` init executes inittab rules, then killing himself with still live childrens. Then kernel stops CPU.

As i understand question, one of solution is:

- remove stop link for gpio-management service
- add script to ensure that gpio-sensible services stopped/killed to inittab
- add script to stop gpio-management service at end

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I understand, rcS is called by inittab when the system start. The rcS script execute S** script with "start" argument. RcK script is called during shutdown. This script execute S** script with "stop" argument. 

So I think I have to modify the rcK script. However, gpio-management service is nowhere to be find in S** script. 

Is gpio-management service initialize in these kind of script?

Comment: SysV and Bysybox-init uses inittab with or w/out runlevels. SystemD uses "targets"

Comment: I dont know that is gpio-management in your system. if it is a service you need to manage rc. edit order or implement runlevels

Comment: >>>"The purpose of this scheduler will be force GPIO management to be the last one to exit."

what you want to shedule?

Comment: I found the solution. When the system shutdown, every systemfile are unmounted. I just modify inittab to make him unmount sysfs as late as possible. So what, it's possible to drive GPIO until the system shutdown